# Is there any edge case difference between using a get; set; property or a GetValue, SetValue method for a singleton service?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using `microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection` with Xamarin Forms, and I have created a service that holds configuration values for the application. These are retrieved and backed up to my database.

Here I specify to the DI the service:

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSingleton<IConfigService, ConfigService>();
   services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>();
   return services;
}
```

My application code uses this Config service to update config values such as the value of the Rev in the Config table.  The update is performed with `UpdateConfig`.

I would like to know if there is any difference between the two ways that I am am getting and setting the value of Rev.

Both look the same to me but I wonder if there is some edge case that I have not considered or is the use of `get; set;` a practice that is not considered to be a good way to do things with DI as it could cause a problem in a way I do not know agout?

Can anyone comment on if there is a difference and if both ways are valid or if one is a preferred way to change the value of and retrieve the value of `Rev`

Here is an example of a service that I would like to have:

```
public partial class ConfigService : IConfigService
{

    private IDatabaseService _databaseService;
    private Config _config;

    public ConfigService2(IDatabaseService databaseService)
    {
        _databaseService = databaseService;
        _config = _databaseService.GetConfig();
    }

    public int Rev
    {
        get => _config.Rev;
        set
        {
            _config.Rev = value;
            _databaseService.UpdateConfig(_config);
        }
    }

    public void GetRev()
    {
        return _config.Rev;

    }

    public void SetRev(int rev)
    {
        _config.Rev = rev;
        _databaseService.UpdateConfig(_config);

    }


}
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why the question is voted down.  Did I make some mistake in the way that I wrote it?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a huge difference.

your

```
public int Rev
```

is called a "Property": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

A property is really just syntactic-sugar, a more convenient way to handle getters and setters. (GetRev & SetRev).

It's a bit nicer from the user of the properties point of view.
They can write

```
Rev = newRev;
```

instead of

```
SetRev(newRev)
```

which seems more "natural" to a lot of people.